# how to use conditions in another cell with filter() function

Tags: google-sheets, filter, average, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet with a table (say A1:Q50), and another sheet where I want to analyze that data.

In the analysis sheet, each row analyzes the data based on different filters, where as the columns are the actual things I analyze. 
Eg, row 1 in the analysis works on all rows of data where B>1, row 2 on all data rows where C<2 and D="foo", row 3 on data rows where E=0, etc..
Column 1 (of analysis sheet) is the average of relevant data rows (based on the filter mentioned above).

For simplicity sake, I'd like to write the condition for each row in the first column of the row, and then reuse that condition in the analysis columns. So, in the example above, the analysis sheet's A1 would be "B>1" then A2 could be

```
=average(filter('data'!A1Q50, <<condition in A1>>))
```

I haven't succeeded in getting the reference to the full condition to work.

Any ideas how to do it w/o writing a custom function?

Comment: Hi Yaron,  I can definitely help you write it with just one formula per row that does the math for all the columns, but need a sample sheet to demonstrate on.  It's too hard to guess or write something in the abstract.

Comment: Hi, 
A very basic example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18O0o8bqxskxkOJTG1bkdrAlu4o6W7czOoQ7t9djYnJk/edit?usp=sharing

Note that I have many types of conditions, based on date, numbers, strings, etc... 
My goal is to find a uniform formula where in each row of the 'analysis' I can simply write the condition in the first column and I don't need to change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of things you can use `QUERY`

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY('data'!A1:Q50, "where "&A1, 0))
```

where A1 is:

```
E=0
```

or:

```
E=0 and B>1 and C<2
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks.
I'm guessing you can't use named ranges in the query, but have to use the column names, right?

Comment: no. its actually possible to have named range in query

Comment: I mean in the query string itself, not the range the query runs on. Is that possible?

Comment: should be possible